# Error defining DbContext of type IdentityDbContext

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constraints, azure-functions, dbcontext

We have an Azure Functions app that uses three databases, one of which is of type "IdentityDbContext".
Out of the blue, after months of happy use of these contexts, after a rebuild, we run into this error when firing up the Function app:

> Method Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.EntityFrameworkServiceCollectionExtensions.AddDbContext: type argument 'xxx.ApplicationDbContext' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TContext'.

We've tried to find a change that might cause this, but we are stumped…

Similar questions in Stackoverflow etc suggest it was an issue in earlier versions of Azure Functions, but should be resolved by now.

This is the class for the offending `DBcontext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
    : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(e => e.Claims).WithOne().HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
}
```

And this is where all hell breaks loose:

```
var services = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddDbContext<MobidotContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("MobidotDbConnection")))
    .AddDbContext<MobilityDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("MobilityDbConnection")))
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, it appeared that an upgrade to Entity framework caused havoc with the IdentityDBcontext. Downgraded back to 2.2.2, and we're back in business.

I have a feeling we're back in dll hell from ten years ago… :-(